# Implementing the StockTwits Widget over SSL without warnings

Tags: javascript, stocktwits

Trying to use the [StockTwits Widget](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/widget) in a web page that is (and must remain) served over SSL.

Since the widget-loader.min.js script link was being called via http, I copied the code to our domain so it would be served over our SSL.  Problem still not solved.  Chrome 25 says my page "ran insecure content" and completely refused to run or even display the widget.

So I dug into the .js file and found this little bit:

```
m=b.ssl?"https://":"http://"
```

Figuring the warning was coming from the widgets CALL to the service, I hacked this line as follows:

```
// add one character    ↓
m=b.ssl?"https://":"https://"
```

Initially I thought I had success, because Chrome 25 loaded the widget!  But my glee was short lived once I saw that the nice GREEN https:// in the address bar had changed to a yellow warning sign.  Clicking it for info revealed a warning: "...displayed insecure content from http://assets1.stocktwits.net....".  {darn}

Since the .js is secure, and the CALL to stocktwits is made with https thanks to the hack, I have to conclude that stocktwits either isn't able or configured to reply over HTTPS.

Do you have any experience with this widget, or see something I am not doing correctly?  TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've fixed the widget to use protocol-less URLs now. Let us know if that fixes this issue for you.

Comment: Thanks!  I am temporarily working on another area of our site, but as soon as I can get some play time I'll re-tinker with this idea.  It'll be a few weeks.  We are looking forward to having this in our site.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the widget is not fully SSL compatible. 
We will look into seeing what would be involved to have an SSL option with the widget. Seems like it could be done with minimal impact.

Comment: Its been my experience with other API's that the protocol used to **call** the service prevails.  Unless my hack does not work like I think it does, it seems like the widget actually drops the connection and switches to http for the response.  Perhaps asynchronous behavior here?  Ideally the widget code should be called without regard to the protocol similar to the various CDN's `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com....."`

Comment: I believe you guys will see this concern more than most websites will, given that your target audience is financial and subscription related sites and are more likely to require SSL. @ChrisCorriveau

Comment: Agree, we will look into this more.